# Laravel - View [$name ] is not find

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I know this question was asked but any answer did not work for me.

Same .blade is in used for different controllers, but only not working for one controller. This is the error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [themes.default.themes.default.general.index_relation] not found.
```

Right path to .blade is `themes.default.general.index_relation`

What I did:

- Restarted the browser
- Clearing browser cache
- Running `php artisan cache:clear`
- Running `composer dumpautoload`
- Deleting the Controller
- Cleaning `storage/framework/views`
- In PHPStorm uncheck option Preserve files timestamps
- Pointing both my development environment and the testing server to
  the same time server
- Creating new .blade with new name for this controller

I still have same error.

Thank´s in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is some command add `themes.default.` prefix to your view string,
Try to render it like:

```
view('general.index_relation');
```

instead of

```
view('themes.default.general.index_relation');
```

Comment: I am using **protected $indexView = "general.index_relation";** in all controller and only this one have double prefix.